# JSON parsing under django framework

Tags: javascript, json, django, python-3.x

I'm currently learning both django and javascript

I passed a json string from python to javascript and this is the string i got.

```
[{"model": "polls.question", "pk": 1, "fields": {"question_text": "anything", "pub_date": "2017-09-07T09:36:07Z"}}, {"model": "polls.question", "pk": 2, "fields": {"question_text": "hi", "pub_date": "2017-09-07T10:01:39Z"}}]
```

whenever I use the JSON.parse method my javascript crashes

javascript:

```
let mylist = "{{ question_list_as_json | escapejs }}";
let temp = JSON.parse(mylist);
```

python:

```
question_list = Question.objects.all()
question_list_as_json = serializers.serialize('json', question_list)
return render(request, 'polls/index.html', {'question_list': question_list, 'question_list_as_json': question_list_as_json})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your context `question_list` but in the template `question_list_as_json`, try it:

```
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    question_list_as_json = serializers.serialize('json', question_list)
    context = {
        'question_list': question_list,
        'question_list_as_json': question_list_as_json
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: sorry i didn't copy the code correctly the json string does pass correctly to javascript but my problem is that i'm unable to pars it

Comment: try single quotes `mylist = '{{ question_list_as_json }}';` without jsescape

Comment: thanks for the help, i did found a syntax problem above the mentioned code i fixed it now when i pars the json i get the following [object Object],[object Object] how do i continue from here

Comment: sorry but this is for `js` expert, i don't sure with correct answer

Comment: no problem you were a great help, thank you, will now look for the method

Comment: glad to help you )